# Is it possible to register with two instances of Eureka simultaneously?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

We have multiple environments for our apps, but not all apps have the same environments. For example:

- App 1 has dev, qa, and prod environments
- App 2 has dev, and prod environments (no qa environment)

We're trying to figure out if there's a simple way to route requests cross-environment so that App 1 in qa has access to App 2's services in dev. The solution that seems to make sense is a way for apps to register with more than one Eureka instance, so that they are discoverable by apps connected to either Eureka. Of course the potential problem there is that how does App 2 know which Eureka to use for its own discovery, but let's assume that App 2 makes no external calls.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this out of the box with Spring Cloud?

The alternate solution I am considering is spinning up additional instances of App 2 to create a qa environment that's just based on the dev environment's code. That would obviously work, but then it's additional instances to maintain and I am hoping there's another way to handle it.

Comment: Spinning up App 2 in qa sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks, we'll go that route.